# Configuration of includedRegions in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I limit the scope of a Jenkins pipeline project to only be built if a file in specific subdirectory is changed using `Jenkinsfile`?

I have a single Git repository with two directories. Each directory contains a separate subproject and I would like to build each subproject separately by Jenkins using `Jenkinsfile`. The project has the following file structure:

```
parent
 |
 +- subA
 |   |
 |   + Jenkinsfile
 |   + more files related to sub project A
 |
 +- subB
     |
     + Jenkinsfile
     + more files related to sub project B
```

The `Jenkinsfile` for `subA` has the following configuration:

```
checkout scm: [
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: '*/master']],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://[path]/parent.git']],
    extensions: [[
        $class: 'PathRestriction', includedRegions: 'subA/.*'
    ]]
]
```

The `Jenkinsfile` for `subB` is similar, the only difference being that it has specified `subB` as `includedRegions`.

In the Jenkins server, I have created two pipeline projects and pointed them to each `Jenkinsfile` respectively. If a file is changed in the folder `subA`, Jenkins pipeline project A is triggered and if a file is changed in folder `subB`, Jenkins pipeline project B is triggered, which is what I expect.

The problem is that the Jenkins pipeline project A is also triggered if a file is changed in `subB` and vice versa.

Jenkins version: 2.3

---

Note: 
Configuring the setting `Additional Behaviours` -> `Polling ignores commits in certain paths` -> `Included Regions` to `subA/.*` or `subB/.*` respectively in the old Jenkins (ver 1.649) GUI results in the expected behavior.

---

Update:

Adding `excludedRegions` to the Jenkinsfiles, e.g.

```
checkout scm: [
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: '*/master']],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://[path]/parent.git']],
    extensions: [[
        $class: 'PathRestriction', excludedRegions: '', includedRegions: 'subA/.*'
    ]]
]
```

does not change the behavior. Both subprojects are still rebuilt, despite files are only changed in one subdirectory.

Comment: If you already have a separate `Jenkinsfile` per submodule, and want to build them independently, why do you specific the parent project's URL in `userRemoteConfigs` then? You could just directly use the URL to the respective submodule's Git repository, and build them as regular Git projects. Or is your goal to build only those changes to `moduleA` and `moduleB` that are actually taken into use by the parent project?

Comment: @sschuberth There is only one Git repo. The project root folder is the parent directory and the submodules are subfolders to the parent directory. The submodules are very small, they are part of the same project, but there is no direct dependency between them.

Using independent Git repos for each submodule (and change to the simple `git url: "https://[path]/moduleA.git”` config in each Jenkinsfile) would indeed work. However that does not explain why a rebuild of project A is triggered when a file outside of its specified `includeRegions` is changed.

Comment: Ah, so when you say "submodule" you do *not* mean [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), right?

Comment: @sschuberth I mean deployable software modules in project subdirectories, not Git submodules. Sorry about the confusion, I have updated the question.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported yet as [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36195) implies.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: So still no solution for this yet?

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue preventing proper function: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36195

It has a workaround, which is to disable remote polling ([$class: 'DisableRemotePoll']):

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
  branches: [[name: "*/master"]],
  extensions: [
    [$class: 'PathRestriction', excludedRegions: '', includedRegions: '<fill me in with regex \n delimited, leave excludedRegions as empty>'],
    [$class: 'DisableRemotePoll']
  ],
  submoduleCfg: [],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "<my git url>", credentialsId: "$GIT_KEY"]]])
```