# Jenkins2 Pipeline detect SCM changes

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I have a pipeline that runs a bunch of jobs. In this case for the subversion trunk. It lets me select the option to poll SVN with a cron-job, but not which repo location to poll.

How can I specify that? Do I need to specify it? Would I rather start a sub job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700730/how-do-i-configure-a-jenkins-pipeline-to-be-triggered-by-polling-subversion):

1. Put the pipeline script into a Jenkinsfile in your repo's root directory (commit it)
2. Change the pipeline definition to "Pipeline from SCM script", add the repo URL, add the credentials
3. Set the polling interval
4. Make a manual commit to your SCM to check if it is picked up correctly